# How to fix "Failed to process @BeforeTask or @AfterTask annotation because: Task with name "application-1" is already running

Tags: spring-cloud-task

I have a Spring Cloud Task application setup to use spring.cloud.task.single-instance-enabled=true.  When using this option, a lock record is created in the TASK_LOCK repository table and my task completes successfully.   This lock record remains even though the task completed.  Subsequent runs fail with "Failed to process @BeforeTask or @AfterTask annotation because: Task with name "application-1" is already running."

I've tried changing the parameters to make the task run unique but this did not work.   If I specify a new task name, I can get it to run once but not twice.   Removing the task lock record manually on the back-end will allow subsequent executions for the same task name.

Am I correct to assume that the task lock should be removed from the table upon completion of the task?

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    task:
      single-instance-enabled: true
  datasource:
    url: ****
    username: ****
    password: ****
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    hibernate: 
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

Data Source Configurer class

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer;

public class DataSourceConfigurer extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {

                public DataSourceConfigurer(DataSource dataSource)

                {
                                super(dataSource);
                }

}
```

Main Application class

```
. . .
@Autowired
       private DataSource dataSource;
       @Bean
       public DataSourceConfigurer getTaskConfigurer() {
              return new DataSourceConfigurer(dataSource);
       }
. . .
```

I'm expecting the execution of a task with a given task name may only run at one time (in a running state).   Once that task is completed, a task with the same name would be allowed to run.

The actual results are showing only one execution of a task with a given task name may run only one time.  Task lock record remains and does not allow subsequent task executions even though the first run is complete.